# Showing next div after filling input

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to display next div with same class when input in current div is filled with value? 
I’ve been trying with .parent and everything i can think off but can’t seem to get logic how it should work
And honestly i can’t even find way to start off

I’ve got bunch of divs filled with inputs and on filling input field next div with input should appear

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var input = $('.active-q').find('input[type=text],select');
  $(input).keyup(function (event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
    // format number
    $(this).val(function (index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                  .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
  });

  ///animation
  // $(".active-q").each(function(i){
  //  $(this).delay(i*1000).animate({'marginLeft':0}, {duration: 500})
  // });
  $('input').blur(function () {
    tmpval = $(this).val();
    if (tmpval == '') {
      $(this).closest('.active-q').addClass('empty');
      $(this).closest('.active-q').removeClass('filled');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.active-q').addClass('filled');
      $(this).closest('.active-q').removeClass('empty');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=“row”>
  <div class=“question col-md-12>
    <input type=“text” name =“basicinfo”>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
  <div class=“question col-md-12>
    <input type=“text” name =“basicinfo”>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
  <div class=“question col-md-12>
    <input type=“text” name =“basicinfo”>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So when the text box of the first div loses focus, then the next div with input should appear? Correct?

Comment: _" I’ve been trying with .parent and everything i can think off "_ Please demonstrate that in your question so we don't waste your time and ours trying that that you already did

Comment: @RyanWilson when input has something in it or loses focus

Comment: @j08691 i’ve edited question with js i used

Comment: Not an answer, but that blur function could be made more concise as `$(this).closest('.active-q').toggleClass('empty', tmpval === '').toggleClass('filled', tmpval !== '');`

Comment: @Dzonikas I added an answer below, I think it should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need something like the following:

```
//element is your input element that has just been filled or blurred
//Since your inputs are decendants of the divs with class "row",
//Go up the nodes to the ancestor with class "row"
//Then get it's sibling, the next div with class "row"
//Then get it's child div and add class active-q and remove class empty
function showNextQuestionDiv(element){
    const $currentInput = $(element);
    const $ancestorRowDiv = $currentInput.closest('div.row');
    const $nextRowDiv = $ancestorRowDiv.next('div.row');
    const $nextQuestionDiv = $nextRowDiv.find('div.question');

    if($nextQuestionDiv.hasClass('active-q') === false){

        $nextQuestionDiv.removeClass('empty');
        $nextQuestionDiv.addClass('active-q');
    }

}
```

Comment: `const $nextQuestionDiv = $(element).closest('div.row').next('div.row').find('div.question')`

Comment: @Tibrogargan Or you can do it like that. :)

Comment: Thank you both :) ( and all people who helped :))

Comment: @RyanWilson `siblings()` is actually incorrect here, as it will always select the 1st `div.row`, (except when `$ancestorRowDiv` is the 1st div obviously)

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks for the correction, updated my answer.